# rollback a complete folder in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, rollback

How do I rollback a **complete folder** (files that have been added later should also be removed and files that were deleted should also come back in) using TFS 2010?

Either I am doing something wrong or I should be really ... suprised that a feature this crucial for any version control system is not there.

Comment: You rollback changesets, and you can specify a folder you want to rollback. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: When rolling back to a changeset for a whole folder, files that have been added later are not removed and files that were deleted are not coming back in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning your workspace or creating a new one?

The rollback functionality (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776.aspx) should return deleted files and remove newly added ones.

To test this you should be able to create a new workspace get latest from the changeset prior to rollback.  Then create a new workspace and get latest from the changeset checked in after the rollback.

Creating the new workspaces is not required but is just used to rule out environmental/workspace issues.